# How do I create a view from the user interface, and get the code to create it programmatically?

Tags: views

Is there a way to get the program code for creating a view from an existing view?

I first created a dummy view with the user interface. I would like to get the code that I have to insert in my module to create that view, so that my module replicates what I did with the UI. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

That is a feature that the Views module already has. In Drupal 7, you need to follow these steps:

- In the page listing all the views defined in a site, select the "Export" operation

  [image: screenshot]
- In the next page, the Views module will show you the code that defines the view.

This is only the code that defines the views.

Another way, is the following one; in this case, you get the complete code to use to write a module.

- Enable the Bulk Export module that is listed under the modules that are part of the Chaos Tools Suite module
- On admin/structure/bulk-export, select the view(s) you want to export in a module, and enter the name of the module

  [image: screenshot]
- After you click on the "Export" button, the next page will show you the content of the .info, the .module, and the .inc file you can use to write a module that implement the view

In Drupal 6, you need to follow these steps:

- Enable the View Exporter module that is part of the Views module (I am referring to version 6.x-3.0.)
- On admin/build/views/tools/export, select the view(s) you want to export in a module, and enter the name of the module

  [image: screenshot]
- After you click on the "Export" button, the next page will show you the content of the .info, the .module, and the .inc file you can use to write a module that implement the view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use feature module for the same. It will export the views into module and if you delete the views and enable the module, it will create views again.

Feature : http://drupal.org/project/features

You can find the tutorial of the feature in the drupal.org.